# what is the format of RSA public key modulus and exponent in .net?

Tags: rsa

in a short question: How can I fill in RSAParameters if I have having the following input from the third party?:

Modulus: 123456

Exponet: 111

In a long story, I use the following code:

RSACryptoServiceProvider  RSAalg = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);

RSAParameters    rsaPublic = RSAalg.ExportParameters(false);

then I can get modulus and exponent of the rsa public key in byte[]. In order to write these information in the asn.1 format

```
      RSAPublicKey ::= SEQUENCE {
           modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
           publicExponent    INTEGER   -- e
       }
```

I use a asn.1 library to convert byte[] to its bigInteger format, but this byte[] should be in the format like {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'} assuming it is decimal.

But it seems like rsaPublic.modulus and rsaPublic.exponent are not in this format, there are many not-digits in the byte[] of the modulus and exponent. So what is the format of rsaPublic.modulus and rsaPublic.exponent, and how convert them into a byte[] with the format like {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

The `byte[]` values represent the byte-encoded Big Endian representation of the big integers.  That's almost, but not exactly, the same as the DER encoding.

For `Modulus`, the `RSAParameters` structure expects the DER value but with the optional sign-padding `0x00` byte removed. For `Exponent` it's the same.

If you have a private key structure then `D` must have the same length `byte[]` as `Modulus` (which might mean you have to prepend `0x00` values).  `P`, `Q`, `DP`, `DQ`, and `InverseQ` are all required if `D` is specified, and they must all have **exactly half** the length of `Modulus`, which may require removing DER padding bytes or may require inserting some.

Comment: If true then my answer is wrong and I'll delete it. How did you figure this out?

Comment: @JamesKPolk It's a little bit tortured, but https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/6225e48bd3945f245a9f96fe46ee1cfc05fa57bd/src/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates/tests/PublicKeyTests.cs#L129-L152. If you read the relevant certificate in a DER/ASN.1 decoder you'll see that the expected Modulus and Exponent are the same as the DER values without the tag and length (and the padding byte for the modulus value).  Though I'm a little worried my answer implies the tag and length are supposed to be present...

Comment: It's absolutely terrible that the API doesn't even specify what the contents of the byte arrays should be (signed / unsigned, endianess). I don't know which dunces first created the description, but it should be amended ASAP.