# Generate RSA Public Key from modulus and exponent, Java to C#

Tags: java, c#, rsa, clover

I'm new to Crypto and working with RSA keys in general.  I'm working with a Clover payment API and I have a working Java example that I'm running in VSCode.  From a Base64 public key, it parses the modulus and exponent, generates a public key and then encrypts some card data.  I'm trying to duplicate the functionality in C# without success.

```
taPublicKey = "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"

final byte[] key = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(taPublicKey);

// BigIntegers in java are signed, we prefix by a zero byte to make sure we get unsigned.
// Not a problem for the exponent since it's heavily left-padded with zeros already
final byte[] unsignedPrefix = {0x00};
final BigInteger modulus1 = new BigInteger(ArrayUtils.addAll(unsignedPrefix, Arrays.copyOfRange(key, 0, 256)));
final BigInteger exponent1 = new BigInteger(Arrays.copyOfRange(key, 256, 512));
final KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
return factory.generatePublic(new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus1, exponent1))

...
```

I understand that a byte is different in Java and C# and I may be having trouble with the endianness of byte arrays but again, I'm new to this and after a ton of searches and looking at different posts, I can't seem to find a working solution for encryption that is correct and accepted by the payment API.  Apparently, from the Java and PHP examples I've seen, the first 256 bytes are the modulus and the second 256 bytes are the exponent.

```
byte[] publicKey = Convert.FromBase64String(taPublicKey);

byte[] modulus1 = new byte[256];
Array.Copy(publicKey, modulus1, 256);

byte[] exponent1 = new byte[256];
Array.Copy(publicKey, 256, exponent1, 0, 256);

// This may need to be unsigned, adding 0 to end??
BigInteger mod1 = new BigInteger(modulus1.Concat(new byte[] { 0 }).ToArray());            

// Exponent is left padded with a bunch of 0's
// Hardcoded for now with Java results, RSACrptoServiceProvider can't import Exponent > 4 bytes
// BigInteger exp1 = new BigInteger(exponent1);
BigInteger exp1 = new BigInteger(415029);

RSAParameters rSAParameters = new RSAParameters
{
   Modulus = mod1.ToByteArray(),
   Exponent = exp1.ToByteArray()
};

//Add prefix to credit card number, using Clover test card number for sandbox per instructions
string cardToEncrypt = "00000000" + "6011361000006668";
string base64EncryptedCardNumber = null;
using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048))
{
   try
   {
      rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
      rsa.ImportParameters(rSAParameters);

      var encryptedUtf8CardNumber = rsa.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cardToEncrypt), true);

      // convert encrypted card to base64 per instructions
      base64EncryptedCardNumber = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedUtf8CardNumber);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      // Handle this
   }
   finally
   {
      rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
   }
}

return base64EncryptedCardNumber;

...
```

Encryption seems to work but something is not correct, API responds with Invalid Request as well.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Write the public key to a PEM file. Then use OpenSSL to validate and display the contents and to compare it with the original public key. I recommend learning the raw DER format of a public key. That way you will understand bits versus bytes. For example, you would prepend a 0 bit only if the most significant bit of a number is 1 to ensure it is encoded unsigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is predominantly big endian, and so is RSA if you use it according to PKCS#1.

The Java code is not very elegant as they could have used [`BigInteger(int signum, byte[] magnitude)` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-int-byte:A-) to indicate a positive integer (RSA only works with positive integers).

C# is predominantly little endian, although it is officially platform dependent for the base types (which is a very stupid design decision). However, the [default constructor that takes a byte array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-numerics-biginteger-ctor(system-byte())) is explicitly little endian.

Now you could of course first reverse the array and then concatenate the zero byte to the end. However, it would be much clearer if you'd use [the more elaborate constructor that takes booleans (yuck) for the sign and endianness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-numerics-biginteger-ctor(system-readonlyspan((system-byte))-system-boolean-system-boolean)).

That would give you:

```cs
BigInteger mod1 = new BigInteger(new ReadOnlySpan(modulus1), true, true);
```

instead of:

```cs
BigInteger mod1 = new BigInteger(modulus1.Concat(new byte[] { 0 }).ToArray());
```

I'd strongly recommend to use constants `UNSIGNED` and `BIG_ENDIAN` set to `true` so that the constructor makes more sense when reading the code.

Just for completeness I'd also do the same thing for the public exponent. The public exponent is **usually** 65537 nowadays, but other values are absolutely valid, including ones that have as many bits as the modulus (and would therefore be considered a negative value if the most significant bit is considered a sign bit).

However, this is all not required as it seems that you could [directly use the byte arrays for `RSAParameters`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39727938/589259) without changing the order of the bytes or prefixing with `0x00`.

Comment: Thanks Maarten, great information!  I do believe I'm making some progress but unfortunately, I'm attempting to replace the payment gateway in an existing class library that is .NET framework 4.6.1.  So, it doesn't appear that I have access to the more elaborate BigInteger constructors.  When I try and use the byte arrays directly for RSAParameters it throws a 'bad data' exception when importing.  Appears that there is a 4 byte exponent limit.

Comment: But the good news is that if I reverse the arrays and concatenate a 0, my BigInteger values are what I'd expect.  I'm still getting an Invalid Request from the payment API, so I feel there may be something wrong with my RSACryptoService Provider usage even though it's pretty straightforward.  The Java example uses BouncyCastle, with 'RSA/None/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding' transformation.  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @ElkDev That's right, the platform does require the users to have a 32 bit maximum for the exponent. Best to break things off if the exponent is too big (that's hardly ever used anyway) or otherwise just encode it using the minimum number of bytes.

Comment: I'd recommend skipping the BigNum altogether. Just copy 256 bytes for the modulus and the 3 or 4 bytes for the public exponent without reversing or anything. After that there still can be a problem with the encryption algorithm, but you'll have to create a separate question for that I suppose as the code is missing and the question has already been answered.