# Converting C# RSA private key into a form BCrypt can understand

Tags: c#, c, cryptography, rsa, bcrypt

I need help using BCrypt to communicate between my C# app and my C app. Specifically, I need to imbed the private key inside my C application and then imbed the public key inside my C# app since my C# needs to send data and my C app which needs to be able to decrypt the data. Later the C# code will be running on a server but for now it's all being tested locally. Anyways the issue I am having is that I am getting a `0x80090005` aka `NTE_BAD_DATA` error code originating from my 'BCryptImportKeyPair' function call. This tells me that my calls to 'bcrypt' are working since the BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider function succeeded. Anyways the following is my C code.

```
// The following is a global field (total length is 1163)
unsigned char g_privateKeyBlob[] = { 0x52, 0x53, 0x41, 0x32, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x11, 0xEA, 0x1C, 0xC5, 0xD3, 0x18, 0x38, 0xF1, 0x57, 0x1D, 0x77, 0x34, 0x59, 0x41, 0xAA, 0x5C, 0x90, 0xA5, 0x6B, 0x97, 0x3E, 0x5B, 0x8C, 0x9F, 0x2F, 0xAB, 0x9E, 0xA8, 0x07, 0x7B, 0x66, 0x2C, 0xC3, 0xBE, 0x1C, 0x59, 0x4F, 0x6E, 0xFF, 0xBA, 0x95, 0x5D, 0xDA, 0xBD, 0xC0, 0x3D, 0x51, 0x3D, 0x61, 0x57, 0xF7, 0xCA, 0xAF, 0x1F, 0x84, 0x9F, 0x09, 0x23, 0x30, 0x20, 0xE6, 0xDD, 0x7A, 0x9F, 0x71, 0x04, 0x20, 0xE6, 0x8D, 0x40, 0x74, 0x01, 0x8C, 0xBE, 0x9D, 0x19, 0xA3, 0x89, 0xA0, 0xF7, 0x03, 0x48, 0xF9, 0x70, 0xC5, 0x0D, 0xEB, 0x31, 0x65, 0xFB, 0xA7, 0x5E, 0x26, 0x11, 0x03, 0xD4, 0xDA, 0xBD, 0x61, 0x9D, 0x8A, 0x3F, 0x0C, 0xA1, 0xB4, 0x03, 0xFC, 0xA5, 0x15, 0x72, 0x4C, 0x3F, 0xB1, 0x5B, 0x03, 0x8B, 0x32, 0x68, 0xBB, 0x00, 0x15, 0x1B, 0xD3, 0x14, 0x80, 0xBE, 0xD4, 0x15, 0x7C, 0x6F, 0x2C, 0xB2, 0x97, 0x43, 0x3D, 0x2A, 0x1C, 0x0A, 0xF6, 0xF0, 0x9D, 0xB4, 0xEF, 0x74, 0x62, 0xBB, 0xF8, 0x9B, 0x32, 0xA9, 0x32, 0x08, 0xB0, 0x8C, 0xC0, 0x1A, 0x60, 0x5A, 0x3F, 0x93, 0x2C, 0x56, 0x0A, 0x7B, 0xED, 0xDD, 0xCC, 0x0B, 0x2D, 0xC2, 0xAC, 0x6A, 0x1B, 0x6F, 0x13, 0x9D, 0xF2, 0xD2, 0x8A, 0x75, 0x83, 0xDA, 0x4F, 0xE5, 0x36, 0xE8, 0xCE, 0x82, 0x7B, 0xAA, 0x16, 0x3A, 0x07, 0xB8, 0x11, 0x6C, 0x42, 0xCF, 0xFC, 0x19, 0x59, 0x6C, 0x43, 0x79, 0xC0, 0xD0, 0x37, 0x5B, 0xE7, 0xA5, 0x7A, 0xCB, 0xDD, 0x06, 0x02, 0x18, 0x5B, 0xE9, 0xD2, 0xF8, 0x6C, 0x0C, 0x87, 0x50, 0x2D, 0x12, 0x04, 0x40, 0x1A, 0xB5, 0x02, 0xA8, 0xE5, 0xFB, 0xD6, 0x96, 0x35, 0x6B, 0x3F, 0xC3, 0x89, 0x30, 0xAE, 0x15, 0x06, 0xD2, 0xC3, 0x0F, 0xE7, 0xE7, 0xA2, 0x8A, 0xF4, 0x63, 0x38, 0xE7, 0xE3, 0xD5, 0x63, 0xB1, 0x85, 0xC0, 0xDE, 0x8A, 0x50, 0xDC, 0x34, 0xEB, 0x3A, 0xDC, 0x0D, 0x61, 0x48, 0x09, 0x18, 0x8F, 0xA9, 0x9D, 0xD7, 0x83, 0xE3, 0x1A, 0x84, 0x20, 0x48, 0x7E, 0x96, 0xA9, 0x5F, 0xA6, 0x3F, 0x49, 0x60, 0x0E, 0xC7, 0x54, 0xB6, 0xCA, 0xFE, 0xC8, 0x91, 0xE2, 0x5F, 0x92, 0x71, 0xE8, 0x10, 0x3A, 0x6B, 0x52, 0xBB, 0x67, 0x77, 0xB9, 0x00, 0x5F, 0xC7, 0x8F, 0xB4, 0x88, 0x42, 0x99, 0x8F, 0xC3, 0xBF, 0xC3, 0xFF, 0x90, 0x08, 0x59, 0xF4, 0xBA, 0xA2, 0x8B, 0xE0, 0x32, 0xA9, 0x11, 0x0A, 0x2C, 0x59, 0xB0, 0xB0, 0x57, 0xBE, 0xF1, 0xC6, 0xC2, 0xC6, 0x7C, 0xAA, 0x72, 0x0E, 0x38, 0xE8, 0x17, 0x8D, 0x3C, 0x31, 0x97, 0x5A, 0x0F, 0xCD, 0xC8, 0xAC, 0xDF, 0x47, 0x03, 0x4C, 0xEE, 0x96, 0xFC, 0x00, 0xDF, 0x22, 0xD4, 0x23, 0x56, 0x07, 0x33, 0xBF, 0xD4, 0x13, 0xF7, 0x7B, 0x22, 0xDF, 0xDD, 0xA4, 0x34, 0xE0, 0x66, 0x87, 0xF7, 0x18, 0xD5, 0x4E, 0xB1, 0x70, 0xF0, 0xEE, 0x40, 0x06, 0x6F, 0x55, 0xDA, 0xE5, 0x30, 0xEC, 0xAC, 0x82, 0x2B, 0xA9, 0x2F, 0x3A, 0x04, 0xEE, 0xB1, 0x55, 0x0E, 0x2A, 0x44, 0x29, 0xC1, 0xC9, 0x50, 0x50, 0x1A, 0x1C, 0xA8, 0x75, 0x47, 0x74, 0x76, 0x4C, 0xE1, 0x09, 0x1A, 0xB1, 0x80, 0x5E, 0x8B, 0x0A, 0xFD, 0xF1, 0xB5, 0x97, 0x67, 0xB0, 0x06, 0x73, 0xC8, 0xE0, 0x60, 0x48, 0x62, 0xC6, 0xD1, 0xCC, 0xDF, 0x7A, 0xE5, 0xFB, 0x80, 0xA1, 0x0D, 0x23, 0x61, 0x78, 0x44, 0x83, 0x16, 0xEC, 0xC2, 0x95, 0x16, 0x1F, 0x9D, 0x3B, 0x8F, 0xB7, 0x2A, 0x2E, 0x73, 0x4D, 0xAB, 0x6A, 0xFE, 0x22, 0x76, 0x4D, 0xC4, 0xE8, 0x2C, 0xF8, 0x0B, 0x91, 0x85, 0x10, 0xF6, 0x66, 0xE4, 0x46, 0x5D, 0x1A, 0x5F, 0x0E, 0xBF, 0xB3, 0xF6, 0x91, 0xEF, 0xE7, 0xDB, 0x52, 0xE1, 0x4D, 0x30, 0xCA, 0xFD, 0xD4, 0x38, 0xC5, 0x5F, 0xC5, 0xB1, 0x6F, 0xEA, 0xDE, 0x5A, 0x57, 0x24, 0x9A, 0xEB, 0x81, 0xF9, 0xF6, 0x72, 0x28, 0x8F, 0xF6, 0x84, 0xD4, 0xF2, 0xC6, 0x2B, 0x0E, 0x55, 0xC2, 0x78, 0x2E, 0xA2, 0xFF, 0x1D, 0x14, 0x76, 0xD0, 0x48, 0x56, 0x44, 0x66, 0x3F, 0x56, 0x4E, 0xA5, 0xF6, 0x74, 0xFA, 0x42, 0x77, 0x36, 0x10, 0xED, 0x57, 0x08, 0x10, 0x0F, 0x88, 0xEB, 0x57, 0x34, 0x7E, 0xCF, 0x27, 0x8B, 0x68, 0x4A, 0x75, 0x71, 0x0B, 0x70, 0x71, 0xA7, 0x35, 0xE6, 0x52, 0x26, 0x51, 0x94, 0x7F, 0xDE, 0x90, 0xB1, 0x7E, 0xCD, 0xDB, 0x99, 0x04, 0xED, 0x6C, 0xA5, 0x19, 0x7B, 0x72, 0x6D, 0xF5, 0xC2, 0xBA, 0xBA, 0xB7, 0xB5, 0xC6, 0xFF, 0x4B, 0xD7, 0xFE, 0x95, 0x25, 0x01, 0x14, 0x25, 0xF1, 0x06, 0x91, 0x3E, 0xE2, 0xF7, 0xDA, 0x78, 0xB8, 0x5B, 0x58, 0x9B, 0xB6, 0xFC, 0xDB, 0xD4, 0xD0, 0x61, 0xFC, 0xD4, 0x1F, 0xFA, 0x0E, 0x77, 0xF2, 0xCA, 0xC0, 0x8E, 0x36, 0xE3, 0xD3, 0xB1, 0x39, 0x4B, 0xDA, 0xEE, 0xF4, 0x3B, 0xC0, 0xA6, 0x95, 0x6E, 0x79, 0xDC, 0xBC, 0x24, 0x62, 0x1A, 0x81, 0x1B, 0x38, 0xA4, 0xCC, 0xAE, 0xD0, 0x89, 0x7C, 0x50, 0x29, 0x1C, 0x3B, 0x2D, 0xFE, 0xEF, 0x56, 0x7A, 0xA6, 0xC5, 0x13, 0x14, 0x10, 0x33, 0xCA, 0xF5, 0x9B, 0x22, 0xB0, 0x0F, 0x52, 0x96, 0xDA, 0x59, 0x3F, 0xCD, 0xE7, 0x5C, 0xFE, 0xBB, 0xC5, 0x3F, 0x07, 0x54, 0x4C, 0xB9, 0x33, 0x01, 0x95, 0xF5, 0x9E, 0xC4, 0x99, 0x84, 0xE6, 0x6D, 0xBB, 0xA8, 0x87, 0xCD, 0x84, 0x94, 0x5C, 0xB3, 0x4B, 0x2D, 0x80, 0xAC, 0xAC, 0x97, 0x0B, 0x5D, 0xB8, 0xE1, 0x4F, 0xAC, 0x90, 0x3F, 0x05, 0xCE, 0x74, 0x08, 0x3C, 0x08, 0xD2, 0x35, 0x4E, 0xF9, 0xC7, 0x01, 0x13, 0x07, 0xA1, 0x04, 0x77, 0x24, 0xB8, 0x77, 0xDA, 0x3F, 0xDE, 0xBA, 0xCF, 0x3A, 0x32, 0xDB, 0x5D, 0xFD, 0xDA, 0x02, 0xEC, 0xFF, 0x4D, 0x49, 0x22, 0x61, 0x54, 0x53, 0xEC, 0x14, 0x50, 0x22, 0x55, 0xA1, 0x34, 0x4A, 0x0A, 0xAD, 0xE1, 0x6B, 0x79, 0xE0, 0x44, 0xEB, 0x06, 0xB6, 0xAC, 0x65, 0xCF, 0x21, 0x9C, 0x9D, 0xD4, 0xB0, 0xCB, 0x70, 0x63, 0x3D, 0xAC, 0xB2, 0x48, 0x2C, 0x55, 0xCD, 0x22, 0x83, 0x3B, 0x95, 0x7D, 0xC7, 0x78, 0xF6, 0x91, 0x7A, 0xCB, 0x89, 0xEA, 0xF9, 0x36, 0xFB, 0x89, 0x8A, 0xDB, 0x4F, 0xB3, 0x8D, 0x9E, 0x89, 0xCF, 0xB0, 0xC1, 0xA8, 0x48, 0x3C, 0x9A, 0x2E, 0x88, 0x1F, 0x37, 0x5B, 0xA6, 0xEF, 0x6B, 0x22, 0x9C, 0x25, 0xBB, 0xC6, 0xF7, 0x78, 0xA1, 0xD0, 0xC1, 0xF3, 0xA0, 0x06, 0xE4, 0x3A, 0x88, 0x08, 0x61, 0x1C, 0x5C, 0x74, 0x3B, 0x99, 0x5C, 0x95, 0x9B, 0x37, 0xE2, 0x54, 0x57, 0x2E, 0x97, 0x22, 0x76, 0xC5, 0x46, 0xBC, 0x5B, 0xF8, 0xB7, 0xDE, 0xFE, 0xC7, 0x31, 0xA0, 0xEB, 0x4D, 0xA3, 0xAC, 0xC1, 0x2D, 0x3D, 0xC9, 0xD5, 0x97, 0x40, 0x43, 0x37, 0x6E, 0x63, 0x97, 0xC1, 0x50, 0xE1, 0x97, 0x9E, 0xCB, 0xC5, 0xBC, 0x09, 0x86, 0x8D, 0xF5, 0xBA, 0xF4, 0xD8, 0x7E, 0xDD, 0x0D, 0x07, 0x94, 0x33, 0x7D, 0xCE, 0x43, 0xA9, 0xD6, 0x70, 0x1B, 0x8A, 0x0C, 0x02, 0xCC, 0x37, 0x3F, 0x0B, 0x68, 0x0B, 0xA4, 0xBE, 0xDF, 0x30, 0xD3, 0x8A, 0x24, 0x06, 0xFE, 0x25, 0xFE, 0x50, 0x56, 0x61, 0xA2, 0x23, 0x20, 0x5F, 0xA5, 0x04, 0x62, 0x19, 0xE7, 0xCD, 0xF5, 0xC0, 0x9C, 0xF1, 0xED, 0x16, 0x2F, 0xED, 0x16, 0x1E, 0x18, 0xB4, 0x80, 0x4F, 0xF8, 0x0D, 0x94, 0xDD, 0xD2, 0xDB, 0xD9, 0x99, 0xE7, 0x7B, 0x58, 0x70, 0x4C, 0xA0, 0x85, 0x19, 0x5C, 0x22, 0xD8, 0x41, 0xD6, 0xFA, 0xF5, 0x00, 0x84, 0x4D, 0x89, 0x01, 0x25, 0xB2, 0xFB, 0x4A, 0xE6, 0x14, 0xB8, 0x9D, 0x19, 0xCD, 0x55, 0xA9, 0xB6, 0x72, 0x23, 0xCB, 0x92, 0x09, 0xDF, 0x2D, 0xD1, 0x46, 0xBC, 0x17, 0x9A, 0x9F, 0xC6, 0xB3, 0xFC, 0x76, 0x94, 0xAE, 0x09, 0x7A, 0x58, 0xE3, 0x9B, 0xCB, 0xFD, 0x54, 0x93, 0x56, 0x27, 0x25, 0xA7, 0xAB, 0x02, 0xBD, 0x67, 0x78, 0xBE, 0x9A, 0xF6, 0xE2, 0x2C, 0xD8, 0x7C, 0x4D, 0x75, 0x9F, 0x8D, 0x05, 0x8E, 0x93, 0x84, 0xE9, 0x75, 0x34, 0xAF, 0xE7, 0xA1, 0x79, 0x37, 0x05, 0xE0, 0x07, 0x24, 0xC4, 0x4F, 0x10, 0x14, 0x24, 0x31, 0xCE, 0x8E, 0x44, 0x2D, 0x67, 0x34, 0xAF, 0xB2, 0xAA, 0x8D, 0xBF, 0xC2, 0x6E, 0x4F, 0x78, 0x02, 0x75, 0xC3, 0x4F, 0xAB, 0xC8, 0xFB, 0x58, 0x1C, 0x36, 0xB3, 0xBD, 0x8E, 0x17, 0xA8, 0xAC, 0xB2, 0x50 }; 

typedef struct  {
    WCHAR Buffer[128]; // 256 bytes for UTF-16 characters.
    USHORT Length;

    UCHAR EncryptedData[256];

} Handshake, * PHandshake;
```

```
PHandshake handshakeData = (PHandshake)buffer;

ULONG privateKeyBlobLength = sizeof(g_privateKeyBlob); 
PUCHAR decryptedData = NULL;
ULONG decryptedDataLength = 0;

NTSTATUS stat = DecryptRsaData(handshakeData->EncryptedData, 256, g_privateKeyBlob, privateKeyBlobLength, &decryptedData, &decryptedDataLength);
```

```
NTSTATUS DecryptRsaData(
    PUCHAR encryptedData, ULONG encryptedDataLength,
    PUCHAR privateKeyBlob, ULONG privateKeyBlobLength,
    PUCHAR* decryptedData, PULONG decryptedDataLength) {

    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE algHandle = NULL;
    BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE keyHandle = NULL;
    NTSTATUS status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
    DebugMessage("DecryptRsaData 1 \n");
    // Open an algorithm provider for RSA.
    status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&algHandle, BCRYPT_RSA_ALGORITHM, NULL, 0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        return status;
    }
    DebugMessage("DecryptRsaData 2 \n");
    // Import the private key.
    status = BCryptImportKeyPair(algHandle, NULL, BCRYPT_RSAPRIVATE_BLOB, &keyHandle,
        privateKeyBlob, privateKeyBlobLength, 0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(algHandle, 0);
        return status;
    }
```

Anyways since I need to imbed the private and public keys here is how I generated them using C#'s (imported with `using System.Security.Cryptography`) RSA encryption algorithm. This code generates the public and private key and then it puts the private key into a form that I can copy and paste into my C program in a form it can read.

```
        public static void GenerateRsaKeys(out string publicKeyXml, out string privateKeyXml)
        {
            using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048)) // Use 2048-bit for security
            {
                publicKeyXml = rsa.ToXmlString(false); // Export public key
                privateKeyXml = rsa.ToXmlString(true); // Export private key

                RSAParameters parameters = rsa.ExportParameters(true);
                byte[] privateKeyBlob = ConvertRsaParametersToPrivateKeyBlob(parameters);
                string hexPrivateKeyBlob = ToHexString(privateKeyBlob);
                Console.WriteLine("PrivateHexBlob:" + hexPrivateKeyBlob);
            }
        }

        public static byte[] ConvertRsaParametersToPrivateKeyBlob(RSAParameters parameters)
        {
            // Magic header for BCrypt RSAPRIVATE_BLOB
            byte[] magic = BitConverter.GetBytes(0x32415352); // RSA2
            byte[] bitLength = BitConverter.GetBytes(parameters.Modulus.Length * 8);
            byte[] publicExponent = ReverseBytes(parameters.Exponent); // Ensure big-endian byte order
            byte[] modulus = ReverseBytes(parameters.Modulus);
            byte[] prime1 = ReverseBytes(parameters.P);
            byte[] prime2 = ReverseBytes(parameters.Q);
            byte[] exponent1 = ReverseBytes(parameters.DP);
            byte[] exponent2 = ReverseBytes(parameters.DQ);
            byte[] coefficient = ReverseBytes(parameters.InverseQ);
            byte[] privateExponent = ReverseBytes(parameters.D);

            // Concatenate all byte arrays together into a single blob
            byte[] privateKeyBlob = ConcatenateByteArrays(magic, bitLength, publicExponent, modulus, prime1, prime2, exponent1, exponent2, coefficient, privateExponent);
            return privateKeyBlob;
        }

        private static byte[] ReverseBytes(byte[] input)
        {
            // Reverse byte array to switch between little-endian and big-endian
            Array.Reverse(input);
            return input;
        }

        public static string ToHexString(byte[] bytes)
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(bytes.Length * 5);
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append("0x");
                sb.Append(bytes[i].ToString("X2")); // "X2" format specifier to get two hexadecimal characters

                if (i < bytes.Length - 1)
                {
                    sb.Append(", ");
                }
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        private static byte[] ConcatenateByteArrays(params byte[][] arrays)
        {
            var result = new byte[arrays.Sum(a => a.Length)];
            int offset = 0;
            foreach (byte[] array in arrays)
            {
                Buffer.BlockCopy(array, 0, result, offset, array.Length);
                offset += array.Length;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Here is what this code produces for the private and public keys along with the code I use to actually encrypt a test string.

```
        public static byte[] EncryptDataWithPublicKey(string dataToEncrypt, string publicKeyXml)
        {
            using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                // Load the RSA public key
                rsa.FromXmlString(publicKeyXml);

                // Convert the data to encrypt to a byte array
                var dataToEncryptBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataToEncrypt);

                // Encrypt the data. OAEP padding is recommended for new applications.
                var encryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(dataToEncryptBytes, false); // Set to true to use OAEP padding

                return encryptedData;
            }
        }


PrivateHexBlob:0x52, 0x53, 0x41, 0x32, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x11, 0xEA, 0x1C, 0xC5, 0xD3, 0x18, 0x38, 0xF1, 0x57, 0x1D, 0x77, 0x34, 0x59, 0x41, 0xAA, 0x5C, 0x90, 0xA5, 0x6B, 0x97, 0x3E, 0x5B, 0x8C, 0x9F, 0x2F, 0xAB, 0x9E, 0xA8, 0x07, 0x7B, 0x66, 0x2C, 0xC3, 0xBE, 0x1C, 0x59, 0x4F, 0x6E, 0xFF, 0xBA, 0x95, 0x5D, 0xDA, 0xBD, 0xC0, 0x3D, 0x51, 0x3D, 0x61, 0x57, 0xF7, 0xCA, 0xAF, 0x1F, 0x84, 0x9F, 0x09, 0x23, 0x30, 0x20, 0xE6, 0xDD, 0x7A, 0x9F, 0x71, 0x04, 0x20, 0xE6, 0x8D, 0x40, 0x74, 0x01, 0x8C, 0xBE, 0x9D, 0x19, 0xA3, 0x89, 0xA0, 0xF7, 0x03, 0x48, 0xF9, 0x70, 0xC5, 0x0D, 0xEB, 0x31, 0x65, 0xFB, 0xA7, 0x5E, 0x26, 0x11, 0x03, 0xD4, 0xDA, 0xBD, 0x61, 0x9D, 0x8A, 0x3F, 0x0C, 0xA1, 0xB4, 0x03, 0xFC, 0xA5, 0x15, 0x72, 0x4C, 0x3F, 0xB1, 0x5B, 0x03, 0x8B, 0x32, 0x68, 0xBB, 0x00, 0x15, 0x1B, 0xD3, 0x14, 0x80, 0xBE, 0xD4, 0x15, 0x7C, 0x6F, 0x2C, 0xB2, 0x97, 0x43, 0x3D, 0x2A, 0x1C, 0x0A, 0xF6, 0xF0, 0x9D, 0xB4, 0xEF, 0x74, 0x62, 0xBB, 0xF8, 0x9B, 0x32, 0xA9, 0x32, 0x08, 0xB0, 0x8C, 0xC0, 0x1A, 0x60, 0x5A, 0x3F, 0x93, 0x2C, 0x56, 0x0A, 0x7B, 0xED, 0xDD, 0xCC, 0x0B, 0x2D, 0xC2, 0xAC, 0x6A, 0x1B, 0x6F, 0x13, 0x9D, 0xF2, 0xD2, 0x8A, 0x75, 0x83, 0xDA, 0x4F, 0xE5, 0x36, 0xE8, 0xCE, 0x82, 0x7B, 0xAA, 0x16, 0x3A, 0x07, 0xB8, 0x11, 0x6C, 0x42, 0xCF, 0xFC, 0x19, 0x59, 0x6C, 0x43, 0x79, 0xC0, 0xD0, 0x37, 0x5B, 0xE7, 0xA5, 0x7A, 0xCB, 0xDD, 0x06, 0x02, 0x18, 0x5B, 0xE9, 0xD2, 0xF8, 0x6C, 0x0C, 0x87, 0x50, 0x2D, 0x12, 0x04, 0x40, 0x1A, 0xB5, 0x02, 0xA8, 0xE5, 0xFB, 0xD6, 0x96, 0x35, 0x6B, 0x3F, 0xC3, 0x89, 0x30, 0xAE, 0x15, 0x06, 0xD2, 0xC3, 0x0F, 0xE7, 0xE7, 0xA2, 0x8A, 0xF4, 0x63, 0x38, 0xE7, 0xE3, 0xD5, 0x63, 0xB1, 0x85, 0xC0, 0xDE, 0x8A, 0x50, 0xDC, 0x34, 0xEB, 0x3A, 0xDC, 0x0D, 0x61, 0x48, 0x09, 0x18, 0x8F, 0xA9, 0x9D, 0xD7, 0x83, 0xE3, 0x1A, 0x84, 0x20, 0x48, 0x7E, 0x96, 0xA9, 0x5F, 0xA6, 0x3F, 0x49, 0x60, 0x0E, 0xC7, 0x54, 0xB6, 0xCA, 0xFE, 0xC8, 0x91, 0xE2, 0x5F, 0x92, 0x71, 0xE8, 0x10, 0x3A, 0x6B, 0x52, 0xBB, 0x67, 0x77, 0xB9, 0x00, 0x5F, 0xC7, 0x8F, 0xB4, 0x88, 0x42, 0x99, 0x8F, 0xC3, 0xBF, 0xC3, 0xFF, 0x90, 0x08, 0x59, 0xF4, 0xBA, 0xA2, 0x8B, 0xE0, 0x32, 0xA9, 0x11, 0x0A, 0x2C, 0x59, 0xB0, 0xB0, 0x57, 0xBE, 0xF1, 0xC6, 0xC2, 0xC6, 0x7C, 0xAA, 0x72, 0x0E, 0x38, 0xE8, 0x17, 0x8D, 0x3C, 0x31, 0x97, 0x5A, 0x0F, 0xCD, 0xC8, 0xAC, 0xDF, 0x47, 0x03, 0x4C, 0xEE, 0x96, 0xFC, 0x00, 0xDF, 0x22, 0xD4, 0x23, 0x56, 0x07, 0x33, 0xBF, 0xD4, 0x13, 0xF7, 0x7B, 0x22, 0xDF, 0xDD, 0xA4, 0x34, 0xE0, 0x66, 0x87, 0xF7, 0x18, 0xD5, 0x4E, 0xB1, 0x70, 0xF0, 0xEE, 0x40, 0x06, 0x6F, 0x55, 0xDA, 0xE5, 0x30, 0xEC, 0xAC, 0x82, 0x2B, 0xA9, 0x2F, 0x3A, 0x04, 0xEE, 0xB1, 0x55, 0x0E, 0x2A, 0x44, 0x29, 0xC1, 0xC9, 0x50, 0x50, 0x1A, 0x1C, 0xA8, 0x75, 0x47, 0x74, 0x76, 0x4C, 0xE1, 0x09, 0x1A, 0xB1, 0x80, 0x5E, 0x8B, 0x0A, 0xFD, 0xF1, 0xB5, 0x97, 0x67, 0xB0, 0x06, 0x73, 0xC8, 0xE0, 0x60, 0x48, 0x62, 0xC6, 0xD1, 0xCC, 0xDF, 0x7A, 0xE5, 0xFB, 0x80, 0xA1, 0x0D, 0x23, 0x61, 0x78, 0x44, 0x83, 0x16, 0xEC, 0xC2, 0x95, 0x16, 0x1F, 0x9D, 0x3B, 0x8F, 0xB7, 0x2A, 0x2E, 0x73, 0x4D, 0xAB, 0x6A, 0xFE, 0x22, 0x76, 0x4D, 0xC4, 0xE8, 0x2C, 0xF8, 0x0B, 0x91, 0x85, 0x10, 0xF6, 0x66, 0xE4, 0x46, 0x5D, 0x1A, 0x5F, 0x0E, 0xBF, 0xB3, 0xF6, 0x91, 0xEF, 0xE7, 0xDB, 0x52, 0xE1, 0x4D, 0x30, 0xCA, 0xFD, 0xD4, 0x38, 0xC5, 0x5F, 0xC5, 0xB1, 0x6F, 0xEA, 0xDE, 0x5A, 0x57, 0x24, 0x9A, 0xEB, 0x81, 0xF9, 0xF6, 0x72, 0x28, 0x8F, 0xF6, 0x84, 0xD4, 0xF2, 0xC6, 0x2B, 0x0E, 0x55, 0xC2, 0x78, 0x2E, 0xA2, 0xFF, 0x1D, 0x14, 0x76, 0xD0, 0x48, 0x56, 0x44, 0x66, 0x3F, 0x56, 0x4E, 0xA5, 0xF6, 0x74, 0xFA, 0x42, 0x77, 0x36, 0x10, 0xED, 0x57, 0x08, 0x10, 0x0F, 0x88, 0xEB, 0x57, 0x34, 0x7E, 0xCF, 0x27, 0x8B, 0x68, 0x4A, 0x75, 0x71, 0x0B, 0x70, 0x71, 0xA7, 0x35, 0xE6, 0x52, 0x26, 0x51, 0x94, 0x7F, 0xDE, 0x90, 0xB1, 0x7E, 0xCD, 0xDB, 0x99, 0x04, 0xED, 0x6C, 0xA5, 0x19, 0x7B, 0x72, 0x6D, 0xF5, 0xC2, 0xBA, 0xBA, 0xB7, 0xB5, 0xC6, 0xFF, 0x4B, 0xD7, 0xFE, 0x95, 0x25, 0x01, 0x14, 0x25, 0xF1, 0x06, 0x91, 0x3E, 0xE2, 0xF7, 0xDA, 0x78, 0xB8, 0x5B, 0x58, 0x9B, 0xB6, 0xFC, 0xDB, 0xD4, 0xD0, 0x61, 0xFC, 0xD4, 0x1F, 0xFA, 0x0E, 0x77, 0xF2, 0xCA, 0xC0, 0x8E, 0x36, 0xE3, 0xD3, 0xB1, 0x39, 0x4B, 0xDA, 0xEE, 0xF4, 0x3B, 0xC0, 0xA6, 0x95, 0x6E, 0x79, 0xDC, 0xBC, 0x24, 0x62, 0x1A, 0x81, 0x1B, 0x38, 0xA4, 0xCC, 0xAE, 0xD0, 0x89, 0x7C, 0x50, 0x29, 0x1C, 0x3B, 0x2D, 0xFE, 0xEF, 0x56, 0x7A, 0xA6, 0xC5, 0x13, 0x14, 0x10, 0x33, 0xCA, 0xF5, 0x9B, 0x22, 0xB0, 0x0F, 0x52, 0x96, 0xDA, 0x59, 0x3F, 0xCD, 0xE7, 0x5C, 0xFE, 0xBB, 0xC5, 0x3F, 0x07, 0x54, 0x4C, 0xB9, 0x33, 0x01, 0x95, 0xF5, 0x9E, 0xC4, 0x99, 0x84, 0xE6, 0x6D, 0xBB, 0xA8, 0x87, 0xCD, 0x84, 0x94, 0x5C, 0xB3, 0x4B, 0x2D, 0x80, 0xAC, 0xAC, 0x97, 0x0B, 0x5D, 0xB8, 0xE1, 0x4F, 0xAC, 0x90, 0x3F, 0x05, 0xCE, 0x74, 0x08, 0x3C, 0x08, 0xD2, 0x35, 0x4E, 0xF9, 0xC7, 0x01, 0x13, 0x07, 0xA1, 0x04, 0x77, 0x24, 0xB8, 0x77, 0xDA, 0x3F, 0xDE, 0xBA, 0xCF, 0x3A, 0x32, 0xDB, 0x5D, 0xFD, 0xDA, 0x02, 0xEC, 0xFF, 0x4D, 0x49, 0x22, 0x61, 0x54, 0x53, 0xEC, 0x14, 0x50, 0x22, 0x55, 0xA1, 0x34, 0x4A, 0x0A, 0xAD, 0xE1, 0x6B, 0x79, 0xE0, 0x44, 0xEB, 0x06, 0xB6, 0xAC, 0x65, 0xCF, 0x21, 0x9C, 0x9D, 0xD4, 0xB0, 0xCB, 0x70, 0x63, 0x3D, 0xAC, 0xB2, 0x48, 0x2C, 0x55, 0xCD, 0x22, 0x83, 0x3B, 0x95, 0x7D, 0xC7, 0x78, 0xF6, 0x91, 0x7A, 0xCB, 0x89, 0xEA, 0xF9, 0x36, 0xFB, 0x89, 0x8A, 0xDB, 0x4F, 0xB3, 0x8D, 0x9E, 0x89, 0xCF, 0xB0, 0xC1, 0xA8, 0x48, 0x3C, 0x9A, 0x2E, 0x88, 0x1F, 0x37, 0x5B, 0xA6, 0xEF, 0x6B, 0x22, 0x9C, 0x25, 0xBB, 0xC6, 0xF7, 0x78, 0xA1, 0xD0, 0xC1, 0xF3, 0xA0, 0x06, 0xE4, 0x3A, 0x88, 0x08, 0x61, 0x1C, 0x5C, 0x74, 0x3B, 0x99, 0x5C, 0x95, 0x9B, 0x37, 0xE2, 0x54, 0x57, 0x2E, 0x97, 0x22, 0x76, 0xC5, 0x46, 0xBC, 0x5B, 0xF8, 0xB7, 0xDE, 0xFE, 0xC7, 0x31, 0xA0, 0xEB, 0x4D, 0xA3, 0xAC, 0xC1, 0x2D, 0x3D, 0xC9, 0xD5, 0x97, 0x40, 0x43, 0x37, 0x6E, 0x63, 0x97, 0xC1, 0x50, 0xE1, 0x97, 0x9E, 0xCB, 0xC5, 0xBC, 0x09, 0x86, 0x8D, 0xF5, 0xBA, 0xF4, 0xD8, 0x7E, 0xDD, 0x0D, 0x07, 0x94, 0x33, 0x7D, 0xCE, 0x43, 0xA9, 0xD6, 0x70, 0x1B, 0x8A, 0x0C, 0x02, 0xCC, 0x37, 0x3F, 0x0B, 0x68, 0x0B, 0xA4, 0xBE, 0xDF, 0x30, 0xD3, 0x8A, 0x24, 0x06, 0xFE, 0x25, 0xFE, 0x50, 0x56, 0x61, 0xA2, 0x23, 0x20, 0x5F, 0xA5, 0x04, 0x62, 0x19, 0xE7, 0xCD, 0xF5, 0xC0, 0x9C, 0xF1, 0xED, 0x16, 0x2F, 0xED, 0x16, 0x1E, 0x18, 0xB4, 0x80, 0x4F, 0xF8, 0x0D, 0x94, 0xDD, 0xD2, 0xDB, 0xD9, 0x99, 0xE7, 0x7B, 0x58, 0x70, 0x4C, 0xA0, 0x85, 0x19, 0x5C, 0x22, 0xD8, 0x41, 0xD6, 0xFA, 0xF5, 0x00, 0x84, 0x4D, 0x89, 0x01, 0x25, 0xB2, 0xFB, 0x4A, 0xE6, 0x14, 0xB8, 0x9D, 0x19, 0xCD, 0x55, 0xA9, 0xB6, 0x72, 0x23, 0xCB, 0x92, 0x09, 0xDF, 0x2D, 0xD1, 0x46, 0xBC, 0x17, 0x9A, 0x9F, 0xC6, 0xB3, 0xFC, 0x76, 0x94, 0xAE, 0x09, 0x7A, 0x58, 0xE3, 0x9B, 0xCB, 0xFD, 0x54, 0x93, 0x56, 0x27, 0x25, 0xA7, 0xAB, 0x02, 0xBD, 0x67, 0x78, 0xBE, 0x9A, 0xF6, 0xE2, 0x2C, 0xD8, 0x7C, 0x4D, 0x75, 0x9F, 0x8D, 0x05, 0x8E, 0x93, 0x84, 0xE9, 0x75, 0x34, 0xAF, 0xE7, 0xA1, 0x79, 0x37, 0x05, 0xE0, 0x07, 0x24, 0xC4, 0x4F, 0x10, 0x14, 0x24, 0x31, 0xCE, 0x8E, 0x44, 0x2D, 0x67, 0x34, 0xAF, 0xB2, 0xAA, 0x8D, 0xBF, 0xC2, 0x6E, 0x4F, 0x78, 0x02, 0x75, 0xC3, 0x4F, 0xAB, 0xC8, 0xFB, 0x58, 0x1C, 0x36, 0xB3, 0xBD, 0x8E, 0x17, 0xA8, 0xAC, 0xB2, 0x50
Public Key:
<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>5zhj9Iqi5+cPw9IGFa4wicM/azWW1vvlqAK1GkAEEi1Qhwxs+NLpWxgCBt3LeqXnWzfQwHlDbFkZ/M9CbBG4BzoWqnuCzug25U/ag3WK0vKdE28baqzCLQvM3e17ClYskz9aYBrAjLAIMqkym/i7YnTvtJ3w9gocKj1Dl7Isb3wV1L6AFNMbFQC7aDKLA1uxP0xyFaX8A7ShDD+KnWG92tQDESZep/tlMesNxXD5SAP3oImjGZ2+jAF0QI3mIARxn3rd5iAwIwmfhB+vyvdXYT1RPcC92l2Vuv9uT1kcvsMsZnsHqJ6rL5+MWz6Xa6WQXKpBWTR3HVfxOBjTxRzqEQ==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>

Private Key:
<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>5zhj9Iqi5+cPw9IGFa4wicM/azWW1vvlqAK1GkAEEi1Qhwxs+NLpWxgCBt3LeqXnWzfQwHlDbFkZ/M9CbBG4BzoWqnuCzug25U/ag3WK0vKdE28baqzCLQvM3e17ClYskz9aYBrAjLAIMqkym/i7YnTvtJ3w9gocKj1Dl7Isb3wV1L6AFNMbFQC7aDKLA1uxP0xyFaX8A7ShDD+KnWG92tQDESZep/tlMesNxXD5SAP3oImjGZ2+jAF0QI3mIARxn3rd5iAwIwmfhB+vyvdXYT1RPcC92l2Vuv9uT1kcvsMsZnsHqJ6rL5+MWz6Xa6WQXKpBWTR3HVfxOBjTxRzqEQ==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent><P>9xPUvzMHViPUIt8A/JbuTANH36zIzQ9alzE8jRfoOA5yqnzGwsbxvlewsFksChGpMuCLorr0WQiQ/8O/w4+ZQoi0j8dfALl3Z7tSazoQ6HGSX+KRyP7KtlTHDmBJP6ZfqZZ+SCCEGuOD152pjxgJSGEN3DrrNNxQit7AhbFj1eM=</P><Q>75H2s78OXxpdRuRm9hCFkQv4LOjETXYi/mqrTXMuKrePO50fFpXC7BaDRHhhIw2hgPvlet/M0cZiSGDgyHMGsGeXtfH9CotegLEaCeFMdnRHdagcGlBQycEpRCoOVbHuBDovqSuCrOww5dpVbwZA7vBwsU7VGPeHZuA0pN3fIns=</Q><DP>uHja9+I+kQbxJRQBJZX+10v/xrW3urrC9W1yexmlbO0EmdvNfrGQ3n+UUSZS5jWncXALcXVKaIsnz340V+uIDxAIV+0QNndC+nT2pU5WP2ZEVkjQdhQd/6IueMJVDivG8tSE9o8ocvb5geuaJFda3upvscVfxTjU/cowTeFS2+c=</DP><DQ>x/lONdIIPAh0zgU/kKxP4bhdC5esrIAtS7NclITNh6i7beaEmcSe9ZUBM7lMVAc/xbv+XOfNP1nallIPsCKb9cozEBQTxaZ6Vu/+LTscKVB8idCuzKQ4G4EaYiS83HlulabAO/Tu2ks5sdPjNo7AyvJ3Dvof1Pxh0NTb/LabWFs=</DQ><InverseQ>XJk7dFwcYQiIOuQGoPPB0KF498a7JZwia++mWzcfiC6aPEiowbDPiZ6Ns0/bion7Nvnqict6kfZ4x32VO4MizVUsSLKsPWNwy7DUnZwhz2WstgbrROB5a+GtCko0oVUiUBTsU1RhIklN/+wC2v1d2zI6z7reP9p3uCR3BKEHEwE=</InverseQ><D>ULKsqBeOvbM2HFj7yKtPw3UCeE9uwr+NqrKvNGctRI7OMSQUEE/EJAfgBTd5oeevNHXphJOOBY2fdU182Czi9pq+eGe9AqunJSdWk1T9y5vjWHoJrpR2/LPGn5oXvEbRLd8JkssjcrapVc0ZnbgU5kr7siUBiU2EAPX61kHYIlwZhaBMcFh755nZ29LdlA34T4C0GB4W7S8W7fGcwPXN5xliBKVfICOiYVZQ/iX+BiSK0zDfvqQLaAs/N8wCDIobcNapQ859M5QHDd1+2PS69Y2GCbzFy56X4VDBl2NuN0NAl9XJPS3BrKNN66Axx/7et/hbvEbFdiKXLldU4jeblQ==</D></RSAKeyValue>


private readonly string PublicKey = @"<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>5zhj9Iqi5+cPw9IGFa4wicM/azWW1vvlqAK1GkAEEi1Qhwxs+NLpWxgCBt3LeqXnWzfQwHlDbFkZ/M9CbBG4BzoWqnuCzug25U/ag3WK0vKdE28baqzCLQvM3e17ClYskz9aYBrAjLAIMqkym/i7YnTvtJ3w9gocKj1Dl7Isb3wV1L6AFNMbFQC7aDKLA1uxP0xyFaX8A7ShDD+KnWG92tQDESZep/tlMesNxXD5SAP3oImjGZ2+jAF0QI3mIARxn3rd5iAwIwmfhB+vyvdXYT1RPcC92l2Vuv9uT1kcvsMsZnsHqJ6rL5+MWz6Xa6WQXKpBWTR3HVfxOBjTxRzqEQ==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>";
byte[] encryptedData = EncryptDataWithPublicKey("Test", PublicKey);
```

Anyways then after sending said data to my C program it generated the error I talked about above. I did verify that all pointers are valid, and that the data received by the C program was the same as what the C# program sent but that part does not really matter because I am fairly sure the issue is my private key is not in the correct form or I generated a private key that was not compatible with the C version of RSA. Also, once I get this working, I will regenerate a new key pair since exposing them to the internet would be a dumb idea but if you have a solution to make these two RSA methods work, please let me know!

Edit:
I modified my code to the following which did invert the Endianness but I still get the same error.

```
        public static byte[] ConvertRsaParametersToPrivateKeyBlob(RSAParameters parameters)
        {
            // Magic header for BCrypt RSAPRIVATE_BLOB
            byte[] magic = BitConverter.GetBytes(0x32415352); // RSA2
            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) Array.Reverse(magic); // Ensure big-endian byte order

            byte[] bitLength = BitConverter.GetBytes(parameters.Modulus.Length * 8);
            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) Array.Reverse(bitLength); // Ensure big-endian byte order

            byte[] publicExponent = EnsureBigEndian(parameters.Exponent);
            byte[] modulus = EnsureBigEndian(parameters.Modulus);
            byte[] prime1 = EnsureBigEndian(parameters.P);
            byte[] prime2 = EnsureBigEndian(parameters.Q);
            byte[] exponent1 = EnsureBigEndian(parameters.DP);
            byte[] exponent2 = EnsureBigEndian(parameters.DQ);
            byte[] coefficient = EnsureBigEndian(parameters.InverseQ);
            byte[] privateExponent = EnsureBigEndian(parameters.D);

            // Concatenate all byte arrays together into a single blob
            byte[] privateKeyBlob = ConcatenateByteArrays(magic, bitLength, publicExponent, modulus, prime1, prime2, exponent1, exponent2, coefficient, privateExponent);
            return privateKeyBlob;
        }

        private static byte[] EnsureBigEndian(byte[] data)
        {
            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) Array.Reverse(data); // Convert to big-endian if system is little-endian
            return data;
        }
```

Comment: If Im not mistaken, NTE_BAD_DATA is validation error from bcrypt which tells that either public or private key have invalid length or you incorrectly build bcrypt blob. Try to investigate sizes of keys and see if you encounter marshaling problems such as endianes/encoding/etc. Also, use OS certificate stores, not embedding - easier to maintain and doesn't lower security.

Comment: Your reverse byte seems incorrect - you should reverse each 4 bytes (machine word), not whole sequence, or lower if your data type is lower than 4 bytes. 1,2,3,4 -> full reverse, 5,6,7,8 -> two reverses, etc. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293255/what-is-the-format-of-rsa-public-key-modulus-and-exponent-in-net

Comment: @eocron I tried the following (view my updated post) which modified my endianness, but I still get the same error thoughts on a solution?

Comment: You still reverting entire array, not by size of data

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78221661/rsa-between-c-sharp-and-cs-bcrypt

Comment: @user246821 not a duplicate this question is essentially solved since the issues was an endianness problem which I circumvented by instead generating the keys from my C program. That being said doing that yielded a new final issue, so I retyped everything instead of adding an extra thousand lines to this question.

Comment: @eocron Yes but I am not able to find proper documentation on the endianness between each, so I decided to reverse the way I am generating keys by generating them from C and then brute force the endianness with the public keys which has less parameters till I get my answer. Although the new issue is that I am not sure if BCrypt works with C#'s native RSA libraries.

Comment: Related:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412838/how-to-import-private-key-in-pem-format-using-wincrypt-and-c  That might provide about half the solution.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Is WinCrypt the same thing as what I am using BCrypt? I think my key conversion is now correct, but I am starting to doubt the compatibility between C#'s native RSA library and BCrypt.