# RSA between C# and C's BCrypt

Tags: c#, c, encryption, cryptography, bcrypt

I am trying to use RSA 2048 to have encryption between my C# and C programs. To accomplish this, I am imbedding the private key inside my C program and imbedding the public key inside the C# program. Then my C# program encrypts a string and sends it to my C program for decrypting. The issue is I am receiving a `0xc000000d` error when calling the `BCryptDecrypt` function inside my C program when I use any padding option other than BCRYPT_PAD_NONE. The issue with this is that C#'s `System.Security.Cryptography` library only has options to use PKCS1 and OAEP which don't seem compatible with BCrypt's version (or my public key is wrong doubtful though). I determined this because setting `var encryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(dataToEncryptBytes, true);` to true means it uses OAEP while false means it uses PKCS1 and when I made these changes, I also modified both `BCryptDecrypt` function calls inside my `DecryptRsaData` function where it always results in a `0xc000000d` error aka INVALID_PARAMETER. Then when I changed to using BCRYPT_PAD_NONE it did not result in an error (since it is not even checking the data anymore) but the resulting PUCHAR after decrypting is gibberish and does not contain my original string.

I originally generated the keys inside my C# program and then copied their keys into each program but that was bad since debugging the public key would be far easier since its only two parameters. So, I instead decided to generate the hex associated with both the private and public keys inside my C program and then copy the private key into an unsigned char array and copy the public key into a C# string for further processing. The following is how I did that.

```
static void PrintKeyInHex(PUCHAR key, ULONG keySize) {
    for (ULONG i = 0; i < keySize; ++i) {

        DebugMessage("%02X", key[i]); // %02X formats the output as two-digit hexadecimal
        if (i + 1 < keySize) {
            DebugMessage(":"); 
        }
    }
    DebugMessage("\n");
}

NTSTATUS GenerateAndPrintKeys() {
    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE hAlgorithm = NULL;
    BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE hKey = NULL;
    NTSTATUS status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
    PUCHAR pbPublicKey = NULL, pbPrivateKey = NULL;
    ULONG cbPublicKey = 0, cbPrivateKey = 0, cbData = 0;

    // Open an algorithm provider for RSA.
    status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&hAlgorithm, BCRYPT_RSA_ALGORITHM, NULL, 0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        DebugMessage("Failed to open algorithm provider.");
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    // Generate the key pair.
    status = BCryptGenerateKeyPair(hAlgorithm, &hKey, 2048, 0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        DebugMessage("Failed to generate key pair.");
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    // Finalize the key (make it usable).
    status = BCryptFinalizeKeyPair(hKey, 0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        DebugMessage("Failed to finalize key pair.");
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    // Export the public key.
    status = BCryptExportKey(hKey, NULL, BCRYPT_RSAPUBLIC_BLOB, NULL, 0, &cbPublicKey, 0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        DebugMessage("Failed to get public key size.");
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    pbPublicKey = (PUCHAR)ExAllocatePoolWithTag(NonPagedPool, cbPublicKey, '1Tag');
    if (!pbPublicKey) {
        status = STATUS_NO_MEMORY;
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    status = BCryptExportKey(hKey, NULL, BCRYPT_RSAPUBLIC_BLOB, pbPublicKey, cbPublicKey, &cbData, 0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        DebugMessage("Failed to export public key.");
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    // Export the private key
    status = BCryptExportKey(hKey, NULL, BCRYPT_RSAPRIVATE_BLOB, NULL, 0, &cbPrivateKey, 0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        DebugMessage("Failed to get private key size.");
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    pbPrivateKey = (PUCHAR)ExAllocatePoolWithTag(NonPagedPool, cbPrivateKey, '2Tag');
    if (!pbPrivateKey) {
        status = STATUS_NO_MEMORY;
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    status = BCryptExportKey(hKey, NULL, BCRYPT_RSAPRIVATE_BLOB, pbPrivateKey, cbPrivateKey, &cbData, 0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        DebugMessage("Failed to export private key.");
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    DebugMessage("Public Key: ");
    PrintKeyInHex(pbPublicKey, cbPublicKey);
    DebugMessage("\n \n");

    DebugMessage("Private Key: ");
    PrintKeyInHex(pbPrivateKey, cbPrivateKey);

Cleanup:
    if (pbPublicKey) ExFreePoolWithTag(pbPublicKey, '1Tag');
    if (pbPrivateKey) ExFreePoolWithTag(pbPrivateKey, '2Tag');
    if (hKey) BCryptDestroyKey(hKey);
    if (hAlgorithm) BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hAlgorithm, 0);

    return status;
}
```

This ensured that my private key was correct which just means I needed to make the public key work with C#'s `System.Security.Cryptography` RSA algorithm. But since I knew the public key ended with the modulus (256 bytes) then the exponent (3 bytes) at the end it was fairly easy. Then since I was not sure on the endianness (also just to cover all the bases) I decided to brute force it by trying all 4 endian combinations and sending it to my C program. By that I mean I would call the following C# `EncryptDataWithPublicKey` method 4 times with an `i` from 0 - 3 ensuring any errors was not due to incorrect endianness. Even so I still received the same issues outlined in the first paragraph all 4 times.

```
        public static byte[] EncryptDataWithPublicKey(string dataToEncrypt, int i)
        {
            RSAParameters rsaParams = ConvertHexToRSAParameters(hexPublicKey, i);
            using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                // Load the RSA public key
                rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParams);

                // Convert the data to encrypt to a byte array
                var dataToEncryptBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataToEncrypt);

                // Encrypt the data. OAEP padding is recommended for new applications.
                var encryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(dataToEncryptBytes, false); // Set to true to use OAEP padding

                return encryptedData;
            }
        }

        private static RSAParameters ConvertHexToRSAParameters(string hexString, int i)
        {
            byte[] bytes = HexStringToByteArray(hexString);
            Console.WriteLine("BytesSize:" + bytes.Length);
            bytes.ToList().ForEach(i => Console.Write(i.ToString() + " "));
            RSAParameters rsaParams = new RSAParameters();

            // Extract the modulus and exponent from the blob
            byte[] exponent = ExtractExponent(bytes, 3); // Assuming 3 bytes for exponent
            byte[] modulus = ExtractModulus(bytes, 256); 

            if(i == 1)
            {
                Array.Reverse(exponent);
                Array.Reverse(modulus);
            }
            else if(i == 2)
            {
                Array.Reverse(exponent);
            }
            else if(i == 3)
            {
                Array.Reverse(modulus);
            }

            rsaParams.Exponent = exponent;
            rsaParams.Modulus = modulus;

            return rsaParams;
        }
```

Anyways once my C program tries to decrypt the original string, I get a `0xc000000d` status when using `BCRYPT_PAD_PKCS1` or `BCRYPT_PAD_OAEP` while `BCRYPT_PAD_NONE` results in no status issues but unreadable data. My assumptions here are either the C library aka BCrypt's `BCRYPT_PAD_OAEP` and `BCRYPT_PAD_PKCS1` are not compatible with C#'s version or I am creating the public keys wrong. I concluded this since I know the private key is 100% valid since its generated by the BCrypt algorithm and I know the public key's Hex is also correct, but I am not certain if I am converting the public keys hex to the correct format. Also, one last note based on earlier testing the `BCryptImportKeyPair` function would fail when I formatted the public key incorrectly inside my C# application, but I am fairly sure that is just a length check which tells me my field lengths are correct but then again, I am also trying every endianness possibility so I am really at a lost to what the issue could be. That being said the following is my C code that I use to decrypt the actual data.

```
unsigned char g_privateKeyBlob[] = { 0x52, 0x53, 0x41, 0x32, ... }; // I cut off the rest since its 539 bytes long

static void DebugPrintEncryptedData(UCHAR* data, ULONG length) {
    for (ULONG i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        DebugMessage("%02X ", data[i]);
        if ((i + 1) % 16 == 0) {
            DebugMessage("\n"); // New line every 16 bytes for readability
        }
    }
    DebugMessage("\n"); // New line at the end
}

                // This code then runs which calls the bellow function and then formats the data in a readable format with the above function
                ULONG privateKeyBlobLength = sizeof(g_privateKeyBlob); // Get the size of your private key blob
                PUCHAR decryptedData = NULL;
                ULONG decryptedDataLength = 0;

                NTSTATUS stat = DecryptRsaData(handshakeData->EncryptedData, 256, g_privateKeyBlob, privateKeyBlobLength, &decryptedData, &decryptedDataLength);
                DebugMessage("FirstDebug Status:%d \n", stat);
                DebugMessage("Status:0x%x \n", stat);
                DebugPrintEncryptedData(decryptedData, decryptedDataLength);
                DebugMessage("Length:%lu \n", decryptedDataLength);
                DebugPrintEncryptedData(handshakeData->EncryptedData, 256);
                DebugMessage("PrivateKeyLength:%lu \n \n", privateKeyBlobLength);

NTSTATUS DecryptRsaData(
    PUCHAR encryptedData, ULONG encryptedDataLength,
    PUCHAR privateKeyBlob, ULONG privateKeyBlobLength,
    PUCHAR* decryptedData, PULONG decryptedDataLength) {

    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE algHandle = NULL;
    BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE keyHandle = NULL;
    NTSTATUS status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
    DebugMessage("DecryptRsaData 1 \n");

    // Open an algorithm provider for RSA.
    status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&algHandle, BCRYPT_RSA_ALGORITHM, NULL, 0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        return status;
    }
    DebugMessage("DecryptRsaData 2 \n");

    // Import the private key.
    status = BCryptImportKeyPair(algHandle, NULL, BCRYPT_RSAPRIVATE_BLOB, &keyHandle, privateKeyBlob, privateKeyBlobLength, 0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(algHandle, 0);
        return status;
    }
    DebugMessage("DecryptRsaData 3 \n");

    // Get the size needed for the decrypted data buffer.
    status = BCryptDecrypt(keyHandle, encryptedData, encryptedDataLength, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, decryptedDataLength, BCRYPT_PAD_PKCS1); // We are failing here
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
         BCryptDestroyKey(keyHandle);
         BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(algHandle, 0);
         return status;
    }
    DebugMessage("DecryptRsaData 4 \n");

    // Allocate the buffer for the decrypted data.
    *decryptedData = (PUCHAR)ExAllocatePoolWithTag(NonPagedPool, *decryptedDataLength, 'decR');
    if (*decryptedData == NULL) {
        BCryptDestroyKey(keyHandle);
        BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(algHandle, 0);
        return STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
    }
    DebugMessage("DecryptRsaData 5 \n");

    // Perform the decryption.
    status = BCryptDecrypt(keyHandle, encryptedData, encryptedDataLength, NULL, NULL, 0, *decryptedData, *decryptedDataLength, decryptedDataLength, BCRYPT_PAD_PKCS1);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        ExFreePoolWithTag(*decryptedData, 'decR');
        *decryptedData = NULL;
        *decryptedDataLength = 0;
    }
    DebugMessage("DecryptRsaData 6 \n");

    BCryptDestroyKey(keyHandle);
    BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(algHandle, 0);

    return status;
}
```

---

**Edit:**
Ok I made some advancements here are the keys for reference. I also included the public key layout in BCrypt.

```
typedef struct _BCRYPT_RSAKEY_BLOB {
    ULONG Magic;         // A magic number identifying the blob type, for public key, this is BCRYPT_RSAPUBLIC_MAGIC.
    ULONG BitLength;     // The length of the key, in bits.
    ULONG cbPublicExp;   // The length of the public exponent, in bytes.
    ULONG cbModulus;     // The length of the modulus, in bytes.
    // Following this header in memory would be:
    // - The public exponent (of length cbPublicExp)
    // - The modulus (of length cbModulus)
} BCRYPT_RSAKEY_BLOB;

Public Key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

Private Key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
```

Above we can see that theres 4, 4-byte hex values at the start in Little-Endian. Magic and BitLength dont matter to us but the next two do. Here we get confirmation that the Exponent is 3 bytes and Modulus is 256 bytes.

```
            byte[] bytes = HexStringToByteArray(publicKey);
            int bitLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 4);
            int cbPublicExp = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 8);
            int cbModulus = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 12);
    
            Console.WriteLine(" \n Exp:");
            byte[] exponent = ExtractExponent(bytes, cbPublicExp, cbModulus); 
            exponent.ToList().ForEach(i => Console.Write(i.ToString() + " "));
            Console.WriteLine(" \n Mod:");
            byte[] modulus = ExtractModulus(bytes, cbModulus); 
            modulus.ToList().ForEach(i => Console.Write(i.ToString() + " "));
```

But the far more interesting thing we notice is that the exponent actually comes before the Modulus which means I was reading it wrong. Also, another thing to point out here is that so far, we have 16 bytes for the defined fields + 3 bytes for the Exponent and 256 bytes for the Modulus which only gives us 275 bytes while our public key is 283 bytes long meaning we have 8 bytes extra. Based on common sense we can see that there are 8 bytes worth of zeros till we get to the last 259 bytes where the first 3 bytes of that is 01 00 01 also known as 65,537 in decimal which is a common Exponent for RSA.

```
        private static byte[] ExtractModulus(byte[] keyBlob, int modulusLength)
        {
            int startIndex = keyBlob.Length - modulusLength; 
            return keyBlob.Skip(startIndex).Take(modulusLength).ToArray();
        }

        private static byte[] ExtractExponent(byte[] keyBlob, int exponentLength, int modulusLength)
        {
            int startIndex = keyBlob.Length - exponentLength - modulusLength;
            return keyBlob.Skip(startIndex).Take(exponentLength).ToArray();
        }
```

So that's that right? Nope, I now know what every byte in the public key represents with 100% accuracy but even after making these changes I still have the exact same issue outlined in the first paragraph. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: OT: *imbedding the private key inside my C program*  That's OK for learning.  It's completely insecure for any real-world usage.  If you have a real need to encrypt data to keep it private, putting a private key into your source code means every version control system, every file system backup, every temporary object file created during compilation, every executable generated from that code, every core file created, every disk the binary was swapped out to, and lots of other places will have that private key in it for anyone and everyone to find and use.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes thats a good point I was going to work on securing it after I get it working.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Nope that was addressing an earlier issue of converting the keys into a form each algorithm can read but I already solved that (read my edit section if you want to double check) but the new issue I am facing outlined in the first paragraph is that even with correct keys decrypting the message still fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is revealed if you look closely at the definitions of `BCRYPT_RSAKEY_BLOB` and `BCRYPT_RSAPUBLIC_BLOB`:

`BCRYPT_RSAKEY_BLOB` is defined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/ns-bcrypt-bcrypt_rsakey_blob#syntax) and looks as follows:

```c
typedef struct _BCRYPT_RSAKEY_BLOB {
  ULONG Magic;
  ULONG BitLength;
  ULONG cbPublicExp;
  ULONG cbModulus;
  ULONG cbPrime1;
  ULONG cbPrime2;
} BCRYPT_RSAKEY_BLOB;
```

The public key you posted is a `BCRYPT_RSAPUBLIC_BLOB` structure, which is defined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/ns-bcrypt-bcrypt_rsakey_blob#remarks) and looks like this:

```c
BCRYPT_RSAKEY_BLOB
PublicExponent[cbPublicExp] // Big-endian.
Modulus[cbModulus] // Big-endian.
```

Note that all of the numbers following the `BCRYPT_RSAKEY_BLOB` structure are in **big-endian** order.
In your C# code, however, you are inverting the exponent and modulus, which is wrong and the main cause of the problem.
There is also a typo in the `ExtractExponent()` call (the third parameter is missing).

Fix:

```cs
private static RSAParameters ConvertHexToRSAParameters(string hexString)
{
    byte[] bytes = HexStringToByteArray(hexString);
    RSAParameters rsaParams = new RSAParameters();

    // Extract the modulus and exponent from the blob
    byte[] exponent = ExtractExponent(bytes, 3, 256);   // Typo: 3rd param missing!
    byte[] modulus = ExtractModulus(bytes, 256);
                                                        // Fix: Remove the inversion of the arrays! 
    rsaParams.Exponent = exponent;
    rsaParams.Modulus = modulus;

    return rsaParams;
}
```

---

*Test:* Using the public key you posted and the plaintext *The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog*, the fixed C# code returns e.g. the following ciphertext:

```
0x89, 0x7a, 0xda, 0x6d, 0x9e, 0x85, 0xc2, 0x1d, 0x76, 0xd6, 0xe2, 0x02, 0xfd, 0x31, 0x7c, 0x7b, 0x56, 0x02, 0x5f, 0x42, 0xd1, 0xb6, 0xc0, 0x36, 0x9f, 0xb3, 0xdc, 0x65, 0x7d, 0x89, 0x4a, 0x05, 0xe8, 0x4e, 0xbd, 0xb1, 0x04, 0x64, 0x80, 0x5c, 0xc3, 0x66, 0x72, 0x98, 0xd5, 0x7f, 0xeb, 0x23, 0x38, 0x61, 0x3d, 0x5c, 0xbd, 0x17, 0xfa, 0x48, 0xfc, 0x75, 0x0e, 0x5b, 0x68, 0x00, 0xae, 0xfb, 0xa9, 0x3d, 0x77, 0x3d, 0xe6, 0x97, 0xca, 0x77, 0x26, 0x2d, 0x8c, 0x9a, 0xfb, 0x2e, 0x52, 0x86, 0x23, 0xff, 0xd6, 0xc6, 0x26, 0x9c, 0x57, 0xd1, 0x54, 0xb8, 0xd1, 0xb0, 0x93, 0x72, 0xd9, 0xf5, 0xd5, 0x15, 0x6a, 0xf3, 0xcd, 0x34, 0xe3, 0x80, 0x79, 0x5f, 0x11, 0x29, 0x4a, 0x7e, 0xce, 0x2f, 0xf7, 0x69, 0x0d, 0xc4, 0xbb, 0x2f, 0x02, 0x1c, 0xf1, 0xf5, 0x75, 0x9c, 0x7c, 0x85, 0x62, 0x9c, 0x3b, 0x54, 0x51, 0x8f, 0xc3, 0xbf, 0xaf, 0xaa, 0xce, 0x6f, 0xdc, 0x6f, 0x74, 0x8d, 0x18, 0xf8, 0x3f, 0x87, 0x10, 0x6e, 0xcb, 0xd7, 0x30, 0x04, 0x20, 0xd7, 0x30, 0xf0, 0x34, 0xae, 0x8f, 0x2e, 0x81, 0x78, 0x67, 0x02, 0x4b, 0x79, 0x5c, 0x8c, 0x81, 0x86, 0x68, 0xca, 0xaa, 0xde, 0x40, 0x41, 0x50, 0x8d, 0xcf, 0x25, 0x8e, 0x72, 0xd0, 0x2f, 0xff, 0x99, 0x5d, 0x86, 0x8c, 0x8b, 0x11, 0x25, 0xd3, 0x70, 0x27, 0xae, 0xf1, 0x35, 0x4f, 0x23, 0x72, 0x0b, 0xb6, 0x04, 0x34, 0xe2, 0x0e, 0xa9, 0x0f, 0xdd, 0x7c, 0x8a, 0x18, 0x6f, 0x40, 0xd7, 0xba, 0xc1, 0x35, 0x68, 0x48, 0xeb, 0xd8, 0x78, 0x77, 0xad, 0x96, 0xb6, 0x83, 0xee, 0xd5, 0xd4, 0xbc, 0x4b, 0x5c, 0x68, 0x07, 0xa3, 0xad, 0x00, 0x22, 0xc3, 0xd9, 0x0f, 0xea, 0x8b, 0x28, 0x54, 0xdb, 0x01, 0x49, 0xfb, 0x1e, 0xde, 0x4f, 0xc7
```

which can be successfully decrypted with your C code and the posted private key.

---

A note on *...meaning we have 8 bytes extra. Based on common sense we can see that there are 8 bytes worth of zeros...*: These 0x00 sequences are due to `cbPrime1` and `cbPrime2`, which are not included in the case of a public key, i.e. have the length 0 (which due to `ULONG` leads to 4 bytes each consisting of 0x00 values)

Comment: Nothing here is different from what I already did. My original post tried encrypting with all 4 endianness possibilities including treating everything as big endian (although the exponent is the same in both big and small endian notation). Secondly, I am using 3 parameters the code you were looking at was the code above the `Edit` section. All in all, everything you have done I already tried yet it still does not work because I am not having an issue with using the C# library my question pertains about using the C# RSA library with BCrypt.

Comment: @UnSure - On my machine, the C code (i.e. the BCrypt code) can successfully decrypt the ciphertext generated with the C# code (with the changes described)! Isn't that what you want, or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: do you mind updating your answer to include the exact string you entered like `EncryptDataWithPublicKey("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog,", i)` and then also mind telling me what padding type you used whether that be with `var encryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(dataToEncryptBytes, true)`  set to true or false. I ask this because although it appears our code is the same I am getting different hex values returned.

Comment: @UnSure - You can run my C# code on .NET Fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/iORfBt. At the end you will find the commented out C/BCrypt code that I use (with adaptations for my environment, but these should not be critical), including the output.

Comment: Well, I mean it created a different hex output for the same string which is normal, and our code runs the exact same yet I still cant decrypt it is using BCrypt without getting the issues outlined in the first paragraph. What padding options did you use inside BCrypt to get it to work?

Comment: @UnSure - I have posted my C/BCrypt code (you can find it in the .NET fiddle link at the end, commented out), this is essentially your code, i.e. I have not changed anything regarding the padding, so PKCS#1 v1.5 is applied (as in the C# code).